# Typewriter effect, curser goes to end of screen then fixes itself

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add a typewriter effect to one of my paragraphs and when I added it, the curser would type everything then continue to go to the left before fixing itself. How do I make it end at the text.

```css
#p12 {
   overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .15em solid orange;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    animation: typing 1.3s steps(10, end), blink-caret .75s steps(50, end) infinite;
}
#p12 {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  
/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}
```

```html
<center>  
<p id="p12" style="color:red;font-size:20px">
<b>  Welcome to my website!  </b> </p> </center>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make the cursor animation stop at the end of the text, instead of moving all the way to the right-hand side of the screen before jumping back as it does now?

Comment: Yes Daniel Beck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use display:flex on a container element to keep the animated element from expanding to full screen width.  (I've also replaced your use of the obsolete `<center>` tag with a `margin:auto` equivalent:)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#center {
  margin: auto;
}
/* Remaining CSS is identical to original */
#p12 {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  animation: typing 1.3s steps(10, end), blink-caret .75s steps(50, end) infinite;
}

#p12 {
  display: inline-flex;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="center">
    <p id="p12" style="color:red;font-size:20px">
      <b>Welcome to my website!</b> 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Can I make the typing have a smoother animation in some way?

Comment: Play around with the `animation:` property. `animation: typing 2.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s infinite;` for example might be something your looking for

Comment: How does this work (why doesn't that line of text fill the width of its container, with the border flush with the right edge)?

Comment: @NattyC the `display:flex` on the parent lets the child collapse to its natural width instead of filling the container. Easier to see if you throw a border on `#center`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper div:

```
<div id="banner-message">
<center>  
<div id="p12" style="color:red;font-size:20px">
<b>  Welcome to my website!  </b> </div> </center>
</div>
```

Try adding this style to wrapper:

```
#banner-message {
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Updated to use a wrapper div to display flex. I was going off of the article that this is based on: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/